# How to use Jenkins credentials in ansible remote host?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I have created a Jenkins Credential (Secret File Type) and want to use this credential in my Ansible playbook.
Ansible is able to able to identify the Jenkins credential when it is running on localhost.
But, when the playbook runs on the remote host, it is unable to identify the value of my Jenkins credential.

My Jenkinsfile stage for Ansible looks like this:

```
stage('Build Image') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'private.key', variable: 'PRIVATE_KEY')]) {
            runAnsible('playbook.yml', [
                env: dev,
                key: PRIVATE_KEY
                .
                .
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> "No such file or directory"

Edit: runAnsible is a part of jenkins-shared-libs. Basically, it is just like calling

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --extra-vars '.....'
```

Comment: what does runAnsible do? I couldn't find this step on ansible plugin docs https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ansible/ . Is it custom method? Anyway I'd suggest to check what is actually passed to ansible. AFAIK, ansible doesn't accept key data as a variable. It only works with files. So runAnsible must write key data to file at some point and pass path to that file to ansible.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks for response!. runAnsible is a part of jenkins-shared-libs. Basically, it is just like calling "ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --extra-vars '.....' " It works perfectly fine, when the playbook runs on localhost, but couldn't locate jenkins-credential file when running on the remote host.